# In Google Analytics's social reports, how can I look at the opt_target parameter used by _trackSocial?

Tags: google-analytics, social-media

After implementing social interactions tracking using `_trackSocial`, how do I look at the `opt_target` parameter in my reports? I can only seem to drill down to social source and action. For example, I'm using...

```
_gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'Twitter', 'Follow', event.data.screen_name]);
```

...bound to Twitter's follow event to track when the follow buttons on my site are pressed, using the opt_target parameter (as per the [social interactions documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial)) to track the username of the Twitter account being followed. However, I don't know where to find that data in my reports, e.g. if I want to see what the most followed account is. If I go to Traffic Sources > Social > Plugins, I can see Twitter, and I can see the Follow events, but I can't drill down any further to see which accounts are followed:

[image: Twitter follow stats]

I'm pretty sure I've seen this in a previous version of Google Analytics. Was it removed? How can I access this data?